# Issues running python script as systemd

Tags: systemd

I am trying to run my own python script that does not return anything and basically runs forever. However, when I try to `systemctl start myservice.service` the service starts (I can see that it is writing to files) but I need to cancel out the CLI. i.e, I have to press `CTRL+C` to be able to use the CLI again and this cancel my script. Or wait for awhile and I get a timeout by systemctl.

The service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Avanza API

[Service]
Type=simple
User=user
Group=user
ExecStart=python3 myscript.py arg1 arg2
WorkingDirectory=/somedir/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```